# Working of electric-tester

Tags: electricity

How does the circuit gets completed when we put an electric-tester glow when we put it in the +ve terminal, when actually the electrons flow from the -ve terminal ?

Comment: Doesn't an electric tester require connection to positive and negative nodes/terminals to work?

Comment: @KyleKanos: no because it uses your body as a giant capacitor. Charges flows on or off you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electric tester displays a light when electrons flow through it. When you touch a negative terminal electrons flow from the terminal through the tester and into you. When you touch a positive terminal electrons flow from you through the tester and into the terminal. Either way the light illuminates.

The current flowing is so small that you don't notice it.

Comment: but it glows only when put in either of the one sockets
please explain

Comment: @D.S.Maura, I don't know specifically how it works in your country, but in my country, one of the two conductors in an electrical outlet is connected to Earth.  You won't feel anything, and your tester won't glow if you touch that one.

Comment: @james large,  Here we put it in the positive terminal and the switch it on. then if there is electricity small bulb in it glows. but when we put it in the other port nothing happens